# appengine ndb init model by kind name

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I need to store data, the problem is that I only know the name of model which is the same as kind name

```
class Tasks(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty()
```

If I have the key already I can do

```
model = ndb.Key(urlsafe=key).get()
model.title = "new tasks"
model.put()
```

Now I need to store *new* entities, how do I do that? thanks

Comment: what is the reason you can't import the Tasks Model in your code?

Comment: I am implementing my own restful and oauth APIs for my little mobile project, importing models is not a problem and can be done by "from Model import *", the reason I do not have Model object is that I get model kind name as string from url as in appspot.com/restful/v1/tasks/ so that's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ndb.Model._kind_map['Tasks'](title='...')
```

or something even more generic, like

```
eval('Tasks')(title='...')
```

You do need to import your models beforehand in both cases.

Or

```
getattr(models, 'Tasks')(title='...')
```

if `models` is the python module where your models live.

Comment: Thank you very much, I knew about "eval" but I wanted avoid it to not slow down script, ndb.Model.kind_map worked well for me, thank you.

Comment: This involves reaching into the internals of the DB API. It's not recommended. Also, using 'eval' with user data is a really, really, really terrible idea.

Comment: Well, if you have at least a couple unittests covering a piece of code that's based on ndb.Model._kind_map, I don't personally think this is so terrible. eval() - definitely agree with you. It's there just for a couple alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Giving your users the ability to instantiate and store models of any kind is probably a Really Bad Idea, so doing a direct mapping is likely the wrong approach. Also, it directly couples your internal datastore representation to your external API, which imposes additional limitations.

Instead, you probably want to define a mapping yourself, like this:

```
model_map = {
    'external_name': model.MyModel,
    # ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For DB

```
from google.appengine.ext.db import class_for_kind
class_for_kind(model_name) -> returns model Class
```

For NDB

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
ndb.Model._kind_map[model_name] -> returns model Class
```